# Recent and Favorite folders in Open/Save dialogs, per application

Tags: windows-7

Open/Save dialogs are those dialogs we use when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

I used to use XFilesDialog in Win2K, but it doesn't work properly anymore in Windows 7.

Windows 7 allows us to set dialogs size and has global Favority links.

But I'd like to be able to have quick access to favorites and recently opened, for files and folders, each of them with a global list and a per-application list.

Could somebody suggest me some app that implements these for Windows 7?

I have tried the following apps, none of them have per-application feature: FileBox eXtender, Direct Folders, FlashFolder, Folder View.

Answer (score 3):

[XFilesDialog version 5](http://www.xdesksoftware.com/downloads.html) is advertised as :

> Now with full support for Win 7 / Win 8 / Win 8.1 / Office 2010 / 2013
>   and 64-bit Windows native support.

so might be worth trying. Virustotal [reports it](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/25acc25c88c3f87373414b6aabae3ed0ba085c1499c0b3621e307f346e4d8d3a/analysis/) as clean.

If this doesn't pan out, a similar survey by [donationcoder](http://www.donationcoder.com/) sums up its results in the article [Best Open/Save Dialog Box Extenders](https://www.donationcoder.com/Reviews/Archive/DialogExtenders/).

One of the comparison criteria is "Separate favorites for specific applications",
and these are the applications for which the answer is "yes"
(some are on your list of discarded, maybe because "favorites" is not the same as "Recent", but I list them for completeness) :

[Direct Folders](http://codesector.com/directfolders)
[FlashFolder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flashfolder/)
[File-Ex](http://www.cottonwoodsw.com/)

Also found thru donationcoder is [Buzz Folders Free](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Buzz-Folders-Free.shtml).

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, you've added a few apps I missed and donationcoder has some more for me to taste. Worth the bounty.